# Issues with Thunderbird in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: thunderbird

Thunderbird is doing weird things, and I don't really know where to start looking for an answer. I can't open Thunderbird from the dock. When opened it appears in the dock as if multiple windows are opened (multiple orange dots), even if that's not the case. I can not click on the image in the dock and see the different windows, when I do that either nothing happens at all, or everything freezes. Thunderbird also has a different lay-out every time I open it. Same story wether I open it from dock or terminal. I have no clue where to even start looking or what I'm looking for to get this working properly. I have Ubuntu 21.10, Thunderbird 91.5.0.

In terminal I get multiple error messages, but don't know how to interpret these.

```
(thunderbird:3757): Gdk-WARNING **: 17:03:55.944: ../../../../../gdk/x11/gdkwindow-x11.c:5653 drawable is not a native X11 window
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!
```

and

```
[calBackendLoader] Using Thunderbird's libical backend
[LDAPModuleLoader] Using LDAPDirectory.jsm
[MsgSendModuleLoader] Using MessageSend.jsm
[SmtpModuleLoader] Using SmtpService.jsm
console.debug: "Trying to load /usr/lib/thunderbird/libotr.so"
console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so.5 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "Trying to load libotr.so from system's standard library locations"
console.log: (new Error("Cannot load required OTR library", "resource:///modules/OTRLib.jsm", 109))
console.debug: "Successfully loaded OpenPGP library librnp.so version 0.15.2+git20210806.dd923a4e.MZLA from /usr/lib/thunderbird/librnp.so"
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

###!!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PClientManager::Msg_ExpectFutureClientSource Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)

console.debug: "Found 0 public keys and 0 secret keys (0 protected, 0 unprotected)"
console.debug: "Successfully loaded optional OpenPGP library libgpgme.so.11 from system's standard library locations"
console.debug: "gpgme version: 1.14.0-unknown"
IPDL protocol error: Handler returned error code!

###!!! [Parent][DispatchAsyncMessage] Error: PClientManager::Msg_ForgetFutureClientSource Processing error: message was deserialized, but the handler returned false (indicating failure)
```

Comment: The error messages in the terminal don't seem to be worrying.  I get similar messages as you.  When you run it and there are "multiple orange dots", can you see if the process is running (i.e., using `ps` or `top`)?  Unrelated to Thunderbird, but I've had cases where a window opens up by default as a very small window.  I guess I had closed it last time as a small window and it saved its "size" that way.  I guess the size of the window is stored as a file somewhere (I don't know where).  You might want to find that file and erase / edit it.  Perhaps someone here can help you with that.

Comment: Something else you can try is to create a new user account.  And run Thunderbird from that.  If it runs fine, then it's a problem with some local information about Thunderbird in your own account.  If it doesn't run fine, then it's a problem with Thunderbird in your system.

Comment: Hi Ray, thanks for this. It seems indeed to work fine when making a test user. Could this have something to do with the migration of data from a back-up? What could I do to fix it? I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Close thunderbird, rename your .thunderbird folder. Launch thunderbird: a new .thunderbird folder is created with factory default settings. Reconfigure your account. Locally stored mail (under "Local Folders" ) can eventually be moved to the appropriate location under the new folder so it is available again.

Comment: hmm... there are multiple thunderbird folders, and I can't seem to rename them...

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al | grep -i thunderbird` and `ls -al .thunderbird`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Hi @heynnema - thanks for following up. In the end I uninstalled thunderbird and installed a different version (named Thunderbird and not Thunderbird Mail in snap) For now at least this seems to work fine. Though sometimes it uses a lot of CPU for (for now) unknown reasons.

Comment: @iii Yeah... the snap versions can suck. Glad you got it working.